# Span tag is shown as text in Drupal Bootstrap subtheme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is something I've never seen, the `span` tag is shown as text inside an `a` tag.

If I modify a letter of the link, then press enter with Firebug, the `span` gets correctly interpreted as HTML.

I am using Bootstrap theme for Drupak 7, using it as parent theme.

The problem can be seen in http://jsfiddle.net/wa5z3L7j/, but I disabled every CSS and it is still shown as text.

This is the firebug console:

[image]

This is how it is seen:

[image]

CSS applied to `a` element:

```
*::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul::after {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) transparent transparent;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    margin-top: -3px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
}
*::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header .nav__primary .sf-menu > li > a {
    border: medium none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #777;
}
.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul {
    padding-right: 2.5em;
}
.sf-menu > li > a {
    color: #6f6f6f;
    font: 13px/18px Ubuntu;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.nav > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.sf-menu a {
    color: #13a;
}
.sf-menu a {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    padding: 0.75em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sf-menu a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
a {
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    background-color: transparent;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Navbar's code:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <nav class="nav nav__primary clearfix" role="navigation">
                                                                    <ul class="menu nav sf-menu navbar-nav sf-js-enabled sf-arrows"><li class="first leaf active"><a class="active" href="/drupal7/">Principal</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a data-scroll="" data-target="#comunicaciones-internas" href="/drupal7/comunicaciones-internas">Comunicaciones Internas</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a data-scroll="" data-target="#accesos-sistemas" href="/drupal7/accesos-sistemas">Accesos a Sistemas</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a data-scroll="" data-target="#agenda-contactos" href="/drupal7/agenda-contactos">Agenda de Contactos</a></li>
</ul>                                                                                                    <ul class="menu nav sf-menu navbar-nav secondary sf-js-enabled sf-arrows"><li class="first last expanded dropdown"><a href="/drupal7/user" class="sf-with-ul">Mi cuenta &lt;span class="caret"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</a><ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none;"><li class="first last leaf"><a href="/drupal7/user/logout">Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>                                                                                            </nav>
                        </div>
```

**EDIT:** I am seeing that in jsfiddle the less than and grater than symbols are being interpreted as an HTML code instead, I will check the source code. Maybe there is something related to the charset.

**EDIT 2:**

> (SOLUTION)

In case you have this problem, I've looked into the 'l' function of Drupal and saw that it was checking for an `html` option in the 3rd parameter, or else it would output escaped string.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7

So, I've added `$opcionesLink['html'] = true;` in `function MYTHEME_menu_link(array $variables)` function, when generating the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the following code:

```html
Mi cuenta &lt;span class="caret"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
<!--------^^^^------------------^^^^^^^^-----^^^^
```

The `&lt;` will be interpreted as `<` and the `&gt;` will be interpreted as `>`. Please make sure you sanitize the code before going live. Change it to:

```html
Mi cuenta <span class="caret"></span>
```

Comment: That is being interpreted by Firefox when copying-pasting to jsfiddle. The code is generated in PHP as follows: `$element['#title'] .= ' <span class="caret"></span> ';`. Maybe drupal is escaping it some way, but in Firebug it shows correct.

Comment: @JorgeeFG Does it come well in View Source?

Comment: Yes, see my images. Or you mean Firefox's source code option?

Comment: @JorgeeFG Yes... Ctrl + U... View Source.

Comment: It is shown as you said: `Mi cuenta &lt;span class=&quot;caret&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt; ` maybe it is Drupal escaping it, I will Google it to see what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly... You got it there.